# Tengo problemas al intentar usar shared_ptr en CodeBlocks

Tags: c++

El dia de ayer mi ordenador portatil dejo de funcionar y ahora me he visto forzado a realizar mis tareas en mi otro ordenador antiguo. He iniciado un nuevo proyecto para poder llevar a cabo mis deberes pero al intentar usar los shared pointers. Obtengo el siguiente error:

C:\Users-\Desktop\EDA\arbresBinaris1\ArbreBinari.h|20|error: 'shared_ptr' does not name a type; did you mean 'char16_t'?|

No entiendo porque aparece este error, si estoy usando el #include .

A continuación comparto mi codigo para ver si alguien es capaz de resolver mi duda.

```
#define ARBREBINARI_H

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class ArbreBinari
{
public:
    ArbreBinari();
    ArbreBinari(const ArbreBinari &a, const ArbreBinari &b, const char &c);
    bool esBuit() const;
    char Contingut() const;
    ArbreBinari FillEsquerre() const;
    ArbreBinari FillDret() const;
private:
    struct Nus
    {
        char cont;
        shared_ptr<Nus> fe, fd;
        Nus();
        Nus(const shared_ptr<Nus>&a, const shared_ptr<Nus>&b, const char&c);
    };

    shared_ptr<Nus> arrel;

};

#endif // ARBREBINARI_H

#include "ArbreBinari.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

ArbreBinari::Nus::Nus()
{
// pre: -
// pos: s’inicialitza el node
    fe = fd = NULL;
}

ArbreBinari::Nus::Nus(const shared_ptr<Nus> &a, const shared_ptr<Nus> &b, const element &c)
{
    fe = a
         fd = b;
    cont = c;
}

ArbreBinari::ArbreBinari()
{
// pre: -
// pos: crea un arbre buit
    arrel = NULL;
}

ArbreBinari::ArbreBinari(const ArbreBinari &a, const ArbreBinari &b, const element &c)
{
// pre: - (error: bad_alloc)
// pos: crea un arbre amb els paràmetres donats
    arrel = shared_ptr<Nus>(new Nus(a.arrel, b.arrel, c)); // bad alloc
}

bool ArbreBinari::esBuit() const
{
// pre: cert
// post: cert si l’arbre és buit
    return (arrel == NULL);
}

char ArbreBinari::Contingut() const
{
// pre: cert (error: arbre buit)
// post: retorna una còpia de l’element que hi ha a l’arrel
    char res;
    if (esBuit())
        throw("L’arbre es buit");
    else
        res = arrel->cont;
    return res;
}

ArbreBinari ArbreBinari::FillEsquerre() const
{
// pre: cert (error: arbre buit)
// post: retorna el fill esquerre de l’arrel (no una còpia!)
    ArbreBinari res;
    if (esBuit())
        throw("L’arbre es buit");
    else
        res.arrel = arrel->fe;
    return res;
}

ArbreBinari ArbreBinari::FillDret() const
{
// pre: cert (error: arbre buit)
// post: retorna el fill dret de l’arrel (no una còpia!)
    ArbreBinari res;
    if (esBuit())
        throw("L’arbre es buit");
    else
        res.arrel = arrel->fd;
    return res;
}


#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "ArbreBinari.h"

using namespace std;

const int MIDA = 1000;

void preordre_binari(const ArbreBinari & a);

int main() {
    char entrada[MIDA];
    cin.getline(entrada, MIDA);
    ArbreBinari a(entrada);

    cout << "Preordre: ";
    preordre_binari(a);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1):

El código tiene varios errores. En primer lugar el que preguntas:

```
<source>:19:9: error: 'shared_ptr' does not name a type
   19 |         shared_ptr<Nus> fe, fd;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Si bien incluyes el archivo correspondiente, `shared_ptr` forma parte del espacio de nombres `std`. Puedes arreglarlo con `using namespace std;` o anteponiendo `std::` antes de cada `shared_ptr`.

También algunos errores de tipeo. Por ejemplo:

```
<source>:38:81: error: 'element' does not name a type
   38 | ArbreBinari::Nus::Nus(const shared_ptr<Nus> &a, const shared_ptr<Nus> &b, const element &c)
      |                                                                                 ^~~~~~~
<source>:38:1: error: no declaration matches 'ArbreBinari::Nus::Nus(const std::shared_ptr<ArbreBinari::Nus>&, const std::shared_ptr<ArbreBinari::Nus>&, const int&)'
   38 | ArbreBinari::Nus::Nus(const shared_ptr<Nus> &a, const shared_ptr<Nus> &b, const element &c)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Se debe a que el tercer parámetro está declarado como `const char&` sin embargo tú escribiste `const element &`.

Algo similar ocurre con el constructor `ArbreBinari::ArbreBinari(const ArbreBinari &a, const ArbreBinari &b, const element &c)`.

También:

- Olvidaste un **;** en `fe = a`.
- En la función `main` no existe un constructor para un arreglo `char` de 1000 elementos o `char*` en su defecto:

  ```
  <source>:115:26: error: no matching function for call to 'ArbreBinari::ArbreBinari(char [1000])'
    115 |     ArbreBinari a(entrada);
        |                          ^
  ```

[Aquí](https://godbolt.org/z/azq9s4xb6) puedes ver todas las correcciones hechas.